# Is there a way to get the Spectrum Color Picker to out put HEX and not RGB?

Tags: jquery, colors

I currently am using BGrins JQuery Spectrum Color Picker in a VS 2013 project. The color picker's out when reading the submitted form is RGB in this project I am required to store the color chosen as a HEX string. Is there a way for the color picker to output HEX string?

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
var t = $('#colorpickerid').spectrum("get");
console.log(t.toHexString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
                $('.color-picker').spectrum({
                    preferredFormat: "hex", // Here
                    type: "color",
                });
```

Docs: https://seballot.github.io/spectrum/#options-preferredFormat